# Unable to apply if condition in Html.haml in my rails project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have been assigned this tiny front end change.
What I am trying to achieve here is, get only student id if the first condition meets and get only student name if the second condition meets.
How ever if the first condition meets,i get what I desire. But if the second condition meets, i get both. Please help

```
  - if @form_settings.formable_type == "Campaign" and @form_settings.students.present?
%label.control-label Student Name
.grid.margin15

  = f.select :student_id, options_for_select(@form_settings.students.map{ |c| [c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name, c.id] }), {include_blank: "Select Student"}
```

- if @form_settings.formable_type == "Campaign"  and @form_settings.enable_student_name == true and @form_settings.students.present?
  %label.control-label Student Name
  .grid.margin15

  = f.input :student_name, label: false, placeholder: 'Student Name', input_html: { class: 'control-field' }

  if @form_settings.formable_type == "Campaign" and @form_settings.enable_student_name == true and @form_settings.students.present? %label.control-label Student Name .grid.margin15

  = f.input :student_name, label: false, placeholder: 'Student Name', input_html: { class: 'control-field' }

Comment: Is it wise to use break condition over here? I feel that should serve the purpose

Comment: Please edit this question and format the code propery. On Stackoverflow you can use \`\`\` to delimit code blocks. However this code screams that you have way too much logic in your view and should refactor.